# How can I auto rotate in Samsung Galaxy?

Tags: samsung, auto-rotation

Coming from a Huawei P9 Lite, I recently moved to a Samsung Galaxy A30s.

While on my other phone it had an Auto rotate icon, I can't find one at the moment.

[image: Samsung Galaxy A30s panel layout]

I've gone to Settings and searched for the term "rotate" but no results were found.

So, when I'm on a webpage

[image: Surfing web in Android Android Samsung Galaxy]

And rotate it, notice that it appears a new icon in the bottom right

[image: Before rotating]

And I need to click in it to actually rotate

[image: After rotating]

During the first days, this was kind of ok, but now I'm tired of having to click always in that icon and waiting for it to appear (sometimes even requiring to do the rotation movement multiple times).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where it says "Portrait", clicking in it changes to "Auto rotate"

[image: Auro rotation active in Samsung Galaxy A30s]

and then auto-rotation gets active.

Notice that if the phone is rotated using the method mentioned in the question, then one won't see "Portrait" but "Landscape"

[image: Landscape Samsung Galaxy A30s]